# Need some help on servlet and jsp

Tags: servlets

Basically my servlet is running a method to extract data out from the Database and pass it to JSP page. However, i will need to run this method every 10 secs to check if there is new data inside the database and if there is i would need it to refresh the jsp page. How can I go around doing this?

Comment: I think it is better to take it the other way: make your JSP call (using an ajax request) your servlet  to ask for the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler) to schedule the database query every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java script and ajax on your jsp page.

Using java script you can reload whole page after some interval with [location.reload()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) method. Same thing you can do with  `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" Content="Desired-interval-in-Seconds">` in your jsp

If you want to use partial rendering you can also use ajax where you won't need to reload your whole page accept your updated portion of your page.

below is a sample code for using ajax

```
(function callOnInterval() {
$.ajax({
url: 'Url', 
success: function(data) {
  $('.yourClass').html(data);
},
complete: function() {
  // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
  setTimeout(callOnInterval, interval-in-milliseconds);
}
});
})();
```

here setTimeout(function, interval) calls function specified on specified interval in milliseconds

For using above function ajax() you will need [jQuery.](http://jquery.com/download/)